# RxJs concatMap is emitting only one http stream out of many

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, concatmap

I have been trying to get stream of objects in a sequencial order, however concatMap is not working for me. With mergeMap I get the stream but no in a sequencial order.

Below is my code I am trying:

```
this.result
    .pipe(
        map((result: Result) => {
            return result.contents
            .map((content: Content) =>  this.databaseService
                .getResource<Resource>('Type', content.key) // http call in service
            )
        }),
        mergeMap((requests: Observable<Resource>[]) => {
            return from(requests)
            .pipe(
                concatMap((resource: Observable<Resource>) => resource), // ----> Trigger only once.
                filter((resource:Resource) => resource.status === 'active'),
                skip(this.pageIndex * this.PAGE_SIZE),
                take(this.PAGE_SIZE),
            )
        }),
    )
    .subscribe({
        next: (resource: Resource) => {
            console.log(resource) // resource stream
        },
        complete: () => console.log('completed')
    });
```

Comment: If `mergeMap` gives you multiple emissions, but `concatMap` does not, it would seem that your "resource observables" are not completing.  Do you see multiple emissions if you add a `take(1)` inside your `concatMap`?  `concatMap(resource => resource.pipe(take(1))`

Comment: Yay... Its working!! 
But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concatMap` will only process one observable source at a time.  It will not process subsequent sources until the current source completes.

In your case the observable from `this.databaseService.getResource()` is not completing.  To force it to complete after the first emission, you could append a `take(1)` like this:

```js
concatMap((resource: Observable<Resource>) => resource.pipe(take(1))
```

Alternatively, if the call to `databaseService.getResource()` is only meant to emit a single value, you could modify your service to emit only a single value.

> // http call in service

Note: If you are using the Angular HttpClient, a typical get request will complete when the response is received. So you can probably have your `getResource()` method return the oservable from the http.get() call.